# Cannot Sign In Google using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, firefox, google-signin

I'm trying to **sign in into google using *Selenium***. Unfortunately it stops me right after I insert the e-mail. I read through the internet that is a **common issue** and I tried everything like:

1. use **Firefox**
2. disable **2-key verification**
3. *allow* **less secure app**
4. and others (I cannot remember because this problem has already taken me **6 hours with no solution**, I'm going *crazy*).

HELP ME!

What can I do?

this is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# set the firefox webdrive (THIS WORKS)
FIREFOX_DRIVER_PATH = "C:\\Development\\geckodriver.exe"
s = Service(executable_path=FIREFOX_DRIVER_PATH)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=s)

driver.get("*my_site*")

# google log-in (THIS WORKS)
GOOGLE_BUTTON_XPATH = '*my_google_button_xpath*'
google_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, GOOGLE_BUTTON_XPATH)
google_button.click()

# email input (THIS WORKS)
EMAIL_INPUT_XPATH = '*my_email_xpath*'
email_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, EMAIL_INPUT_XPATH)
email_input.send_keys("*sample_mail@gmail.com*")
email_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


# XXX--------AND NOW I'M STUCK:--------XXX
# COULDN'T SIGN YOU IN
# this browser or app may not be secure
```

(**I'VE ALSO TRIED WITH CHROME and CHROME DRIVER**, even though in the code above I use Firefox)

Comment: What is the error that you've been facing ?

Comment: Google doesn't allow me to complete the Sign In procedure, it stops me to the E-mail input (once I insert the e-mail it says 'this browser or app may not be secure' instead of asking for the password).